# How to make a column sortable in Dashboard in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have been populating my dashboard page with tables without rendering any `html`. But i need to sort or filter table according to a column value which has boolean value in the db. Nothing happens with the `sortable` tag

```
tab "test" do
        columns  do
          panel "test" do

            table_for Test.all do

              column "Name", :name

              column "status", :status, :sortable => :status  # this needs to be sortable


            end
          end
        end
      end
```

Is it possible in `ActiveAdmin Dasboard`?

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
```

Comment: https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html shows you how to implement a filter on an index page

Comment: i suppose that's not showing the case that i am looking for! It's not an example of dashboard page . Though i have tried it on my dashboard page which was showing error

Comment: ahh good point - this post suggets if you want it on your dashboard you need a custom partial which you render: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178000/how-to-add-a-filter-to-active-admin-dashboard

Comment: i actually tried that but didn't work

Comment: I can't really do much with  'it didn't work'

Comment: ok, first of all, i am trying to use sortable rather than filter, so i am trying in other direction, seems like using sortable tag has no effect and it shows no error, but just doesn't generate the sortable column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs help in the future to customize the sorting:

```
test_order = if params[:order]
              params[:order].gsub(/[^a-z_]/,'').gsub(/_(asc|desc)$/, ' \1') #sanitize and convert to order expression
            else
              "status desc" #default
            end

table_for Test.all.order(test_order), sortable: true, class: 'index_table'  do

              column "Name", :name, sortable: false #to hide sorting name

              column :status
            end
          end
        end
```

resource taken from: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4483#issuecomment-237073696